# Drupal 7 Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: 7

I am working on a new Drupal 7 site and I am randomly getting connection errors to my server.

I am getting "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data." in Chrome and Connection reset Errors in firefox. They are sporadic and tough to replicate. I call my service provider (MediaTemple) and they are unable to replicate the problem.

I am honestly at a loss and will look into any ideas given.

Comment: It looks like a server problem...what kind of server do you have? Do you have mod-security enable it? do you have enable rewrite in apache? your logs tells you anything else?

Comment: I think I might have fixed it. I added the following parameters to my .htaccess file: 
php_value max_execution_time 200 php_value max_input_time 200 php_value output_buffering 1024. Things are zipping along now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something else as well. It turns out that I was using a beta version of a module that was spitting out so many error messages that it was crashing apache.

Best advice I can give is to stick to trusted and tested modules.